# wxPython, error when trying to get value from textctrl

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am trying to learn Python and wxPython; I am making a simple window that should print the contents of a textctrl element on the console. However, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 't_username'
```

Here is the interested portion of the code:

```
import sys, wx
app = wx.App(False)

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def Login(self, e):
        tmp = self.t_username.GetValue()
        print tmp

    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(400, 250))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        m_login = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_OK, "Login", size=(100, 35), pos=(150,165))


        t_username = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, pos=(100, 50), size=(150, 30))
        m_login.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Login)

frame = Frame("Login Screen")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I tried to change the name of the Frame class, the Bind line to

```
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Login, m_login)
```

and removing self. from tmp, but it didn't work.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make t_username an attribute of the Frame class by adding *self.* in front of it.

```
import wx
app = wx.App(False)


class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def Login(self, e):
        tmp = self.t_username.GetValue()
        print tmp

    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(400, 250))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        m_login = wx.Button(
            panel, wx.ID_OK, "Login", size=(100, 35), pos=(150, 165))

        self.t_username = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, pos=(100, 50), size=(150, 30))
        m_login.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Login)

frame = Frame("Login Screen")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```